# BillingClient Purchase.getProducts() returns multiple identifiers

Tags: android, billing, android-billing, play-billing-library

Previously, to get the product `id`, the `getSku()` method was used, which returned singular value.

In the 4.0.0 version of the BillingClient library, the `getSkus()` method was added (https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/release-notes#4-0)

In version 5.0.0, the `getSku()` method was removed totally, and `getSkus()` was replaced with `getProducts()`, whose documentation says just “Returns the product Ids.” (https://developer.android.google.cn/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/Purchase?hl=zh-cn#getProducts())

I cant google any information, why product can have multiple identifiers now?

Answer (score 1):

Since v5.0.0 [`BillingFlowParams.Builder`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/BillingFlowParams.Builder#setProductDetailsParamsList(java.util.List%3Ccom.android.billingclient.api.BillingFlowParams.ProductDetailsParams%3E)) has `setProductDetailsParamsList()` method which indicates there can be multiple products included within one purchase, so to be consistent with this `Purchase` has the `getProducts()` method which returns a list.

(The sample code uses `ImmutableList` but with only a single item: https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/integrate#launch)